# how to parse some specific nodes of xml using sax or dom based on given condition

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax

i am new to jaxp and i am stuck with this i have to parse this xml using either sax or dom.
i have to **ask the user to enter empoyee code and then display the other nodes of that particular employee** 
**for ex**:if user enters 101 then i will show

```
Ename:akshay
ecode:101
dp no.:10
mgr code=201
```

i tried alot but no results,can somebody help.

```
   <employees>
    <employee>
        <Ename>akshay</Ename>
        <Ecode>101</Ecode>
        <EmpSal>2100.0</EmpSal>
        <Department_code>10</Department_code>
        <Manager_code>201</Manager_code>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <Ename>rahul</Ename>
        <Ecode>102</Ecode>
        <EmpSal>21000.0</EmpSal>
        <Department_code>20</Department_code>
        <Manager_code>202</Manager_code>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

**the code i tried to parse this xml**

```
public class ParseUsingDom {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse("emp.xml");
            NodeList list = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
            int count = 0;
            {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
                Element element = (Element) list.item(i);
                String nodeName = element.getNodeName();

                if (nodeName.equals("employee")) {
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("Employee :" + count);
                } else if (nodeName.equals("Ename")) {
                    System.out.println("\tEname:\t"
                            + element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
                } else if (nodeName.equals("Ecode")) {
                    System.out.println("\tECode:\t"
                            + element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
                } else if (nodeName.equals("EmpSal")) {
                    System.out.println("\tEmpsal:\t"
                            + element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
                } else if (nodeName.equals("Department_code")) {
                    System.out.println("\tDepartment_code: "
                            + element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
                } else if (nodeName.equals("Manager_code")) {
                    System.out.println("\tManager code:\t"
                            + element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
                }
            }
        }} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. It would be helpful, if you posted, what have you tried and what was the difficulty.

Comment: i posted what i tried now i need to filter my output based on the Emp code,today is my first day with jaxp i have finding it really difficult to implement the condition as i am not well aware of methods in dom or sax,please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward.

1. Parse the XML as a [`Document`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) with a [`DocumentBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html).
2. Ask the user for an ID. If this is command line, then a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) might help.
3. Select the relevant data from the document. [`XPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html) is probably a good start.

Take these steps individually and figure out how to do them. Put it together and you've got your solution.

Comment: thanks but i have done  till scanner and i have to do this without xpath,i just don't know where and how to pass that value ,it would be great if you could share some small example wihout xpath.

Comment: @akshay - Why do you have to do this without XPath, the APIs are included in the JDK/JRE?